# Init pinia state

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

We use [pinia](https://pinia.esm.dev/) to manage app state. As it's mentioned in title, I'm looking for NuxtServerInit hook analogue for pinia.

A little context: User lands on First page of form; Form calls (f.e.) state.getCountries() to fetch the list of items for one of the select inputs; User selects a country and navigates to Second page, which has to have access to countries list as well; It's ok, when User goes to Second page from the First page; But countries list is empty (obvious) if User refreshes the Second page;

Atm I do like `if (state.countries.length === 0) state.getCountries()`

But, I believe, it's not a good way

Page 1

```html
<template>
   <app-select :items="send.countries" />
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
import { useSend } from '~/store/send'

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
       const send = useSend()

       send.getCountries()

       return { send }
    }
}
</script>
```

Page 2

```html
<template>
   <app-select :items="send.countries" />
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
import { useSend } from '~/store/send'

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {
       const send = useSend()
       // if User refreshed Second page, countries is empty list
       if (send.countries.length === 0) {
           send.getCountries()
       }

       return { send }
    }
}
</script>
```

`store/send.ts`

```js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useSend = defineStore({
    state: () => {
        return {
            countries: []
        }
    },

    actions: {
        getCountries() {
            const res = this.$nuxt.$api.countries.get()
            this.countries = res.data
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Just had the same problem last week, and solved it by doing pretty much what you did. I check if store is empty (I set all values to `null` i.e. `countries: null` by default and make simple check i.e. `if(countries)`). If store is not empty I get data from store and save me a request, if store is empty (page has been refreshed) I get the data via request again. The only alternatives would be saving data in session or similar...

Comment: In addition to @Ricardas comment above, you should persist the data. This way if the user refreshes in page 2, the data would stored on the user's machine and won't be empty.